# io.StringIO vs open() in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

All I could find is this [statement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o):

> The easiest way to create a text stream is with open(), optionally
>   specifying an encoding:
>
> `f = open("myfile.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")`
>
> In-memory text streams are also available as StringIO objects:
>
> `f = io.StringIO("some initial text data")`

But this gives no insight at all on when I should use `open()` over `io.StringIO` and vice-versa. I know that they do not work exactly the same behind the scene. But why would someone go for `open()` in Python 3 ?

Comment: Have you *tried* to open a file with `io.StringIO`?

Comment: Asker didn't specify they were trying to open a file specifically.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Have you _tried_ reading the post ?

Comment: Umm, yes, I have. You say you don't know when to use which. If you had *tried* to use both of them, you would've quickly found the answer.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I'm glad the below answer is there, because it is exactly the situation where I was wondering which to use. Considering both output this exact samething in this situation, I tought it would be relevant to know what's the difference. I really don't see why you pretend I didn't try.

Comment: @Aran-Fey could you tell me which is better when using `csv.reader`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The difference is: `open` takes a file name (and some other arguments like mode or encoding), `io.StringIO` takes a plain string and both return file-like objects.

Hence:

- Use `open` to read files ;
- Use `StringIO` when you need a file-like object and you want to pass the content of a string.

An example with `StringIO`:

```
import csv
import io

reader = csv.reader(io.StringIO("a,b,c\n1,2,3"))
print ([r for r in reader])
# output [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', '2', '3']]
```

It's very useful because you can use a string where a file was expected.

In the usual case, with a csv file on your disk, you would write something like:

```
with open(<path/to/file.csv>, ...) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, ...)
```

Comment: Consice and great example (the exact one that brought me here) thank you!

Comment: Both `open` and `StringIO` take strings. The difference is in what they do with the string.

Comment: @user2357112 Right! I will edit my answer to add this precision!